# How to merge data across multiple objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

Example object:

```
{
people: [
  {
    "Name": "Jimmy",
    "Place": ["USA", "Canada", "United Kingdom"]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Serena",
    "Place": ["USA", "Japan", "Canada", "Thailand"]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Richard",
    "Place": ["USA", "Japan", "China", "United Kingdom"]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Rachel",
    "Place": ["Germany"]
  }
]
}
```

Using this object I need to display each place and the names associated with that place which would look like this:

```
USA
Jimmy, Serena, Richard

Canada
Jimmy, Serena

Japan
Serena, Richard

Thailand
Serena

China
Richard

United Kingdom
Jimmy, Richard

Germany
Rachel
```

Here's my current limited progress.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this with my limited JavaScript experience. Using underscoreJS, I have figure out how to display each person's name and the places that they were with, but that's not what I want. I need it merged as shown above. Here's what I've come up with so far...

```
_.each(people, function (value, key) {
  var name = person[key].Name;
  var place = person[key].Place;
  return name + '<br>' + place;
});
```

Which outputs...

```
Jimmy
USA,Canada,United Kingdom

Serena
USA,Japan,Canada,Thailand

Richard
USA,Japan,China,United Kingdom

Rachel
Germany
```

Can anyone be of assistance? I would prefer an answer using underscoreJS, but I am open to other forms of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse the array for all the countries and add the matching names. Two nested loops will suffice:

```
var arr = [/*...*/];// initial array

// object stores the target structure
var store = {};

// for every person in the list ..
arr.forEach(function(person) {
    // for every country, the person has visited
    person.Place.forEach(function(place) {
        // does the store know the country?
        if (!store.hasOwnProperty(place)) {
            // no, create it
            store[place] = [];
        }
        // add the person the the country
        store[place].push(person.Name);
    });
});

console.log(store);
```

[demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWdp3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your need to merge places first and loop through places and print names if matched:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var places = [];
var os = require('os');
var i, j, len, len1, names;

for (i = 0, len = people.length; i < len; i++) {
   places = _.union(places, people[i].Place);
}
for (i = 0, len = places.length; i < len; i++) {
  console.log(places[i]);
  names = []
  for (j = 0, len1 = people.length; j < len1; j++) {
    if (_.indexOf(people[j].Place, places[i]) >= 0) {
      names.push(people[j].Name);
    }
  }
  console.log("  " + names.join(', ') + os.EOL);
}
```

Comment: @Barry Anders: I could have used _.each() for all those 'for' loops but in this case, it more efficient in terms of speed and memory to use just for loops